# Display individual product video descriptions for multiple videos

Tags: query, product-video, product-description

I am trying to provide video transcripts for each product video in a magento 2 site. I want to pull the transcript from the "video description" field in the admin area, and I have been somewhat successful, but only for a single video. Here is my code:

Transcript.php

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\VideoTranscript\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Transcript extends Template
{
    protected $resource;
    protected $product;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        $data = [],
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getVideoDescription()
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video');
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $productId = $this->product->getId();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from($tableName, ['description'])
            ->joinLeft('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity', 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video.value_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity.value_id')
            ->where('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity.entity_id = ?', $productId)
            ->limit(1);

        $description = $connection->fetchOne($select);
        return $description;
    }
}
```

video_description.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->getVideoDescription()): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createTranscript() {
    const transcript = document.createElement('article');
    transcript.innerHTML = `
        <a style="margin: 0.5em; text-decoration: none;" class="video-description__toggle button btn btn-warning">Show Transcript</a>
        <p style="display: none;"><?php echo($block->getVideoDescription()); ?></p>
    `;
    jQuery('.product.media').append(transcript);
    jQuery('.video-description__toggle').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
    console.log('Transcript generated')
}

require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            createTranscript();
        }, 3500);
    });
});
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I realize that the "limit 1" argument in my query in getVideoDescription(), within Transcript.php is going to have to change, but I've sort of gotten lost/confused at this point. Am I overthinking this, can I just pull the video descriptions in from a frontend only solution?

Thank you in advance for your help and insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue, which is to say, get the intended result. Here's the code in case it's helpful to someone else.

video_description.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->getVideoDescription()): ?>

<?php
$video_array = $block->getVideoDescription();
$json_array = json_encode($video_array);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
let orderedTranscripts = [];

const createTranscript = () => {
    const js_array = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json_array; ?>');

    let PV_datacodes = [];
    let video_datacodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product-video')];

    for (let i = 0; i < video_datacodes.length; i++) {
        let id = video_datacodes[i].getAttribute('data-code');
        PV_datacodes.push(id);
    }

    let transcripts = [];

    i = 0;
    while(i < PV_datacodes.length) {
        transcripts.push(js_array[i].description);
        i++;
    }
    // loop over each transcript in transcripts, assign key value to video_datacodes, push to orderedTranscripts array
    orderedTranscripts = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < transcripts.length; i++) {
        let obj = {};
        obj[video_datacodes[i].attributes[4].value] = transcripts[i];
        orderedTranscripts.push(obj);
    }

    let video_key = '';
    // check active video id, compare against orderedtranscripts key
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('fotorama__active')[0].classList.contains('fotorama-video-container')){
        video_key = document.getElementsByClassName('fotorama__active')[0].getElementsByClassName('product-video')[0].getAttribute('data-code');
    }
    // if video_key matches key in orderedTranscripts, return value
    for (let i = 0; i < orderedTranscripts.length; i++) {
        if (video_key === Object.keys(orderedTranscripts[i])[0]) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('fotorama__caption__wrap')[i].innerHTML = orderedTranscripts[i][video_key];
        }
    }
}

const createButton = () => {
    let transcript = document.createElement('article');
    transcript.innerHTML = `
        <a onclick="createTranscript()" style="margin: 0.5em; text-decoration: none;" class="button btn btn-warning">Show Transcript</a>
    `;
    transcript.style.cssText = 'display: none; visibility: hidden;';
    jQuery('.product.media').append(transcript);
}

const addListeners = () => {
    let elements1 = [...document.getElementsByClassName("fotorama__img")];
    let elements2 = [...document.getElementsByClassName("fotorama__thumb-border")];
    let elements = elements1.concat(elements2);
    Array.from(elements).forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', createTranscript);
    });
}

require(["jquery"], function () {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        createButton();
        setTimeout(() => {
            addListeners();
        }, 3000);
    });
});
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

There may be a better way to do this, in fact there probably is, would love to hear about it if someone has an idea!